# How to upload an image using jsonp

Tags: image, upload, jsonp

Jsonp can be used to fetch data from supporting services but can i use it to upload images. As far as i understand javascript cannot access your file system making it impossible to upload an image using pure javascript techniques.However is there a work around. Can an image be uploaded to a server using jsonp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can just using json. The closest you can get is posting to a seperate iframe. Jquery has a feature where you can post a form to a hidden iframe.
http://aspzone.com/tech/jquery-file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-without-using-flash/

If you are using jquery: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/ajax-upload